# Difference in usage for "> stdout" and ">@ stdout" in TCL

Tags: tcl

I've various commands that use `>@ stdout` and `> stdout` to execute commands as such: `eval exec $commandName 2>@ stderr >@ stdout <@ stdin`. Some of them use `>@` while some of them simply use `>` in front of the stdout or stderr command. I'm trying to make a generalized method of execution, and I noticed if I add the `@` in, it prints everything out to the screen whereas without the @ it doesn't which is what I prefer.

I've read the documentation for eval exec here: https://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl/TclCmd/exec.htm#M20 and I see that the `@` allows to provide a fileId, however if I'm using the default stdout and stderr, it should make no difference if I used the `@` since it defaults to std according to this link: https://zetcode.com/lang/tcl/io/ .

I want to make sure I don't run into any unexpected bugs.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
> stdout
```

redirects the output to a file named 'stdout', not to the stdout file descriptor.

```
>@ stdout
```

redirects the output to the fileId stdout, and will print to the current stdout, 
usually the screen.

Comment: If you _definitely_ want something to go to the screen, always, use `>/dev/tty` on POSIX platforms (i.e., everything other than Windows). Or use Tk to put up a GUI… but `stdout` is just the default destination for output, and goes to a pipe if used in a pipeline, or to a socket or serial line if you've done clever things...

Comment: Alright thanks, and what if I use `<@ stdin` as a general way to execute all commands passed in to my program, but not all tests require input. In that case, will it just not input anything from stdin, for the cases which don't require input.

Comment: Correct, if the program doesn't read stdin, it's not going to use it.